# Noise of monitor when displaying certain colors

Tags: display, noise

My monitor is making noises when certain colors are displayed (my phone can't catch it). Depending on the color, the noise is different pitched. The main culprit seems to be black and gray but also to a lesser expent blue and green. Red and yellow are noise free. This is a quite new monitor (NOC U32P2). The noise is constant when the color is displayed, no flickering or other problems are visible. Are there some options (hardware/ software) that are likely to reduce this? Changing the input hdmi did nothing and I would like to avoid sending the monitor back if otherwise options are possible.

Comment: It's probably coil whine. Replacement is the only option. This may be a general problem with this monitor model.

Comment: Coil whine is a general electronics problem and as gronostaj says it could well be a design issue with the monitor line, not just your particular monitor. It boils down to the power supplies working at different frequencies depending on the load demanded by components causing components to vibrate at frequenies you can hear. It is not really a "flaw" or defect, it's just that due to component tolerance and other things like your mains supply and room temperature can bring even a well designed system to the wrong edge of being audible. Or you might replace it and get lucky with a better one...

Comment: If it *is* due to whine in the PS, try changing brightness levels. It might shift the whine to different colors, if not eliminate it.